# SQLAlchemy Not Substituting Values into Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I have a sqlalchemy query that uses some window functions to implement lag() over a column.  The backend is using Teradata if that matters.

I am receiving a database error from that suggests to me that the parameter values are not being correctly substituted.  If I run the bare query in the database, I get the exact same error.

The tables are defined as extensions to the base class and reflected from the database in the usual way.

The sqlalchemy code:

```
name = 'some_column'
query = self.session\
            .query(func.min(getattr(table,name))\
                .over(partition_by=over_attrs,
                      order_by=getattr(table,name),
                      rows=(1,1)))
```

produces the following sql:

```
SELECT min(my_table_1.my_date) 
OVER (PARTITION BY my_table_1.ban, my_table_1.location 
ORDER BY my_table_1.my_date ROWS 
BETWEEN ? FOLLOWING AND ? FOLLOWING) AS anon_1 
FROM schema.my_table AS my_table_1
```

The error message I get is:

```
(teradata.api.DatabaseError) (3707, "[42000] [Teradata]
[ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error, 
expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier 
or an integer between the 'BETWEEN' keyword and '?'. ") 
[SQL: 'SELECT TOP 25 min(my_table_1.my_date) 
OVER (PARTITION BY my_table_1.ban, my_table_1.location 
ORDER BY my_table_1.my_date ROWS BETWEEN ? FOLLOWING AND ? FOLLOWING) AS anon_1 \n
FROM schema.my_table AS my_table_1'] [parameters: (1, 1)] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

If I run the query in database with the `?` replaced with (1,1), the query runs fine.  If I leave in the `?` then it fails with the exact same error as the sqlalchemy version.

Am I doing something wrong that would cause it to fail in this way or could this be a bug in sqlalchemy?

Versions:

```
SQLAlchemy          1.2.8 
sqlalchemy-teradata 0.1.0.dev0
pyodbc              4.0.23
```

I'm using the Teradata Database ODBC driver v 16.10.

Comment: Could you include the versions of SQLAlchemy, the Teradata dialect extension, and the DB-API driver you are using.

Comment: I updated the question with some additional info.

Comment: Looking at the version of `sqlalchemy-teradata` you're using it'd seem that it is hard coded to use [`tdodbc`](https://github.com/Teradata/PyTd/blob/master/teradata/tdodbc.py) only. I'd poke around it to see if it is receiving and handling the parameters correctly. It is its responsibility to handle parameter binding, given that it is getting them.

Comment: THat's a good call, I'll give it a shot and report back if I learn anything valuable.